# Gradle does not download dependencies for fabric-sdk-java

Tags: dependencies, build.gradle, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-java

I am new to Gradle and trying to integrate and run my java application on hyper-ledger fabric.

I added this code to download the dependencies.

```
repositories {

    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
            url "https://nexus.hyperledger.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"}


dependencies {

     implementation  'org.hyperledger.fabric-sdk-java:fabric-sdk-java:1.4.4'
     implementation group:  'org.hyperledger.fabric-chaincode-java', name: 
                           'fabric-chaincode-shim', version: '1.4.2'
     implementation group:  'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180813'

     testImplementation  'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.4.2'
     testImplementation  'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.11.1'
     testImplementation  'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+'
}
```

Refreshing the `build.gradle` file executes successfully but does not download anything. Please let me know what can be the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used these in my build.gradle

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hyperledger.fabric-sdk-java/fabric-sdk-java
    compile group: 'org.hyperledger.fabric-sdk-java', name: 'fabric-sdk-java', version: '1.4.7'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hyperledger.fabric-chaincode-java/fabric-chaincode-shim
    compile group: 'org.hyperledger.fabric-chaincode-java', name: 'fabric-chaincode-shim', version: '1.4.3'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.owlike/genson
    compile group: 'com.owlike', name: 'genson', version: '0.93'
}
```